# When speaking, my 'V' sounds like 'B.' What can I do to properly pronounce 'V' and 'B'?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english

Can someone please guide me in the direction where I can learn to properly pronounce 'V' and 'B' so that each letter I pronounce is clear?

I have a slight Spanish accent, in case anyone needs to know.

Comment: Practice viciously? Ba-a Ba-a Black sheep....  and you will be victorious.

Comment: Depending on your problem, a phonoaudiologist may help you.

Comment: When you make  B sound you press your lips together.  When you make a V sound you *gently* press your upper teeth against your lower lips.

Answer (score 4):

### The "F"

Are you able to pronounce the letter "f"?  Because both "f" and "v" are  labiodental fricative consonants. The only difference is that "v" is [*voiced.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_fricative)

How do you get better? Practice. Say fricative words over and over until you can distinctly identify how to produce the voiced consonant ("v") and the voiceless consonant ("f").  Take these words for example:

- Fun
- Fair
- Fear
- Finish
- Forum

And then, consider these words:

- Van
- Vear
- Vodka
- Virus

All the words in both sets above are pronounced by pressing your top teeth against your bottom lip and doing one of two things:

- Blowing the air inside your mouth out through and under the teeth
- Vibrating the vocal chords, creating a hum.

Comment: More clear to say "pressing your top teeth against your bottom lip".

Comment: I seem to do fine with 'f's. On Dragon Naturally Speaking it's fine except for when I say 'fact' which comes out as 'back' on the screen. I'm having a real hard time with the 'v's. Can you please tell how I can go about acquiring the services of a local professional who can help me with my pronunciation?